# Call source envvars from within python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my django `settings.py` file, I would like to call an `envvars.sh` file to import things like DB_CREDENTIALS. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
if not os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'): 
    subprocess.call(['source', 'envvars.sh'])

DB_PASSWORD         = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD', '')
```

It works from the terminal, doing `$ source envvars.sh` but not from within python. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: A child process cannot affect the environment of its parent. You need to run your process in an environment that has *already* sourced `envvars.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it as you've described here. But perhaps it'd be better to take a step back and ask why you're doing this?

Since you used a Django tag, can we assume you're running a Django application from some other process (for instance, an Apache WSGI application)? Then, by way of example, you'd simply define these variables in /etc/apache2/envvars, then they'd be available to the Apache process (and thus this code within a Django application). Similarly, defining your variables in /etc/environment might benefit you. It just depends on the invocation / deployment structure of your application.

Additionally, storing your variables in a `.env` file and reading that (instead of doing the a `subpprocess` call to a Shell script, which isn't secure) using a module like [`django-dotenv`](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv) and doing something like:

```
if not os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'): 
    import dotenv
    dotenv.read_dotenv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".env"), True)

DB_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD', '')
```

would also be a good approach. If you are using Django, you can actually initialize this in your `settings.py` file in a `dev` environment.